How to resolve system-key missing on disk
While installing and running an processd using zypper   am getting below error message,  the processd is installed, unable to run as expected, Please help,
error trying to compare the processd system key: system-key missing on disk
Started process Daemon
daemon.go:502: gracefully waiting for running hooks
daemon.go:504: done waiting for running hooks
daemon stop requested to wait for socket activation
processd.service: Deactivated successfully.

I verified the installation which installed it correctly inside the /var/lib/ directory , the error does not say much about the the system key,

This doesn't look like a programming problem. Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/ might be a more appropriate place to ask the question.

Thank you, i forgot,  Posted
